# New product attributes value cannot be saved in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, save

I have created nearly 10 new attributes under product attributes. Its added to attribute set as well.

But now, when I update the product information, the data is not getting saved. Instead, after the product shown successfully saved message, the field is kept empty.

### As in the image attached below, the diamond weight is a new attribute. And value 12 is given. But not getting saved.

[image]

The following shows my php-info()

[image]

Comment: Hi please check you max_input_vars limit in php.ini this may be issue if is less then it does not save data try to increase it.

Comment: @CharulTyagi Increased to 10,000 and still the issue is the same.

Comment: so when are trying to save then what error you are seeing any thing getting  wrong when submitting data.

Comment: @CharulTyagi, everything seems to be right and no errors are shown. But the value is not saved.

Comment: have to checked by phpinfo function that max_input_vars you know sometimes it does not effect.

Comment: @CharulTyagi my phpinfo is updated to the question. Please check.

Comment: Did this ever get solved? I upped my max_input_vars on 2.3.4 EE, and I still can't save new attributes. I can't even re-order them.

Comment: @JithinU.Ahmed Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @AniketPrajapati nope

Answer (score 15):

What I did to get this working was (Magento 2.3.2):

1. Mark the product attribute as required setting "Values required" to "YES"
2. Go to a product, add the attribute, select a value and save
3. If you need the product attribute as optional go back to the attribute edit page and set Values required to "NO"

Answer (score 1):

Try to run those commends from root :-

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush.

Comment: When I did this, the whole server is now showing error. Both for frond end as well as admin panel.

Please help.

Comment: When I tried refreshing the cache, its showing *An error occurred while refreshing cache*

Comment: can you please share the error ?

Comment: Error is fixed. But this does not worked.

Comment: Thank bro. Attributes have worked

Answer (score 1):

First of all confirm that the mode should be developer.

Then,

1. clear var folder
2. clear generated except .htaccess
3. run php bin/magento setup:upgrade
4. run php bin/magento indexer:reindex
5. run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
6. run php bin/magento cache:flush

Please share the screenshot of error that is occurring.

If this solution is helpful please accept.

Comment: I have made changes to many design pages. Will the "run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f" comment replace all those changes? I had an issue like this before. That is why I am asking this.

Comment: Running static content deploy generates files in pub/static folder. Yes all design related changes resides in this folder, so running this command will refresh your css and other design related changes

Comment: Are you still facing any error ?
If so you should share screenshot, so that we may know what is the error.

Comment: I am not able to run the page after running the above comments. Its showing 500 error.

Comment: First check if the mode is set to developer. You will be in need to debug then, check logs if you find something. Place some echo exit in index.php if it is reaching till there.

Comment: you can try one thing more: in app/bootstrap.php ...
uncomment or add this :

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

This might show the error

Comment: 500 issue can be related to permission also, please check once the permission

Comment: Yeah, the issue got solved when the permission is given

Comment: But the the attribute values cannot be saved even after running all the above comments.

Comment: Hi, glad that atlest you fixed the error. Regarding saving of attribute, please check once if the attribute is created in database ?. As Magento uses EAV so there must be multiple entries in various tables. Also for any product just try that if you provide value directly on database then it saved and shown in admin.

Comment: Actually, the attributes where added using the normal methods and are shown in the admin product edit portion. But when the data is been saved, its not getting stored in the database.

Comment: Yes I got the point this might be related reindex, but we tried doing that also but it didnt work. Can you check whats the status of flat catalog (https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-enable-flat-catalog-magento-2.html)

Comment: Also please try once doing in an incognito window.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I moved the Custom Attribute to the "General" group and the values started showing up.

Answer (score -2):

Try these commands.

1. php bin/magento indexer:reindex
2. rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
3. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
4. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f;

Comment: PLEASE do NOT use 777 permissions.  This is a security risk and should NEVER be used in a production environment.  Magento has recommendations for permissions.  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

Comment: Yes, you're right. I updated my answer.